# Number of Data in a row checking

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am building a monopoly game and from what I'm doing I'm almost done, but I want the game to end after 30dice rolls. But the way I want to do it is weird. I need a way to store data and check if the data is upto 30 or not, I mean check the amount of data is a row, I've been looking if **sqlite** or **shared preferences** would do, but can't get anything. Any idea would be welcomed and if you can help review my code too, I wouldn't mind. Thank You.

Comment: Which language? Why not Cookie/Session/Standard Variable as counter? Should it be in Sql? So how is your table strucuture?

Comment: I tagged Android, meaning it's Java

Comment: Android does not mean Java. You can also develop Apps on HTML 5 base for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you realy want to persist it in the Database, you want to have a key-value table `current_game_progress` with an item `dice_rolls` and update this each dice roll.

```
UPDATE current_game_progress SET content = content + 1 WHERE keyname = "dice_rolls"
```

But its a bit overhead. Maybe you want to store it local in a variable and transfer it on "save" action to the database.